# How to check SSL certificates expiration dates loaded into the context in java

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, sslcontext

I would like to make REST web service that check the expiration date of the certificate SSL when my java application is running. Is it possible check the  expiration date of the certificate loaded into the application context at runtime ?

Thanks

Comment: Your SSL certificate is located into a .jks or .p12 keystore at server side, or do you have access to the public certificate in some way? or are you looking for stablish a SSL connection to the REST service to get the current certificate and check the date?

Comment: Do you want to check the client cert (that the client optionally sends to the server) on the server? 
Or in the client, the server cert (that the server always sends to the client)?

Comment: My certificate is located client side into file (.p12). Yes, I can access to the certificate if I go into the machine by Remote Desktop (RDP protocol). I want to check the current certificate that is loaded into java application context memory. I don't want read the certificate from file system (file .p12)

Comment: Is it possible ? Is there way to know the certificate ?